# Loading large JSON Array into HTML unordered list, with only 20 data entries at a time

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json

I have a JSON file with the following format:

```
[
  {
    key1: ["value"], 
    key2: ["value"],
    key3: ["value"]
  },
  {
    key1: ["value"], 
    key2: ["value"],
    key3: ["value"]
  },
 repeat for hundreds of data entries
]
```

So on so forth for hundreds of data entries. I am trying to:

a. Load these values into a  on an HTML page

b. Only do the first 20 entries.

Here is my code so far:

```
$.getJSON( "js/test.json", function( data ) {
      var items = [];
      $.each([0,19], function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li>" + key + ", " + val + "</li>" );
      });

      $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
```

However, attempting it this way gives me:

0, 0

1, 19

I'm sure my code is ridiculously incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0,19]` is an array with two elements: *"0"*, and *"19"*. If you want part of an array, use `slice`.

```
data.slice(0, 20)
```

This returns elements from array `data` starting at index *"0"* up to *but not including* index *"20"*.
As in:

```
$.each(data.slice(0, 20), function( key, val ) {
```

This returns the first 20 elements.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/12jk0t84/)

---

Here's an example how to pull the properties from the object the `each` method is currently looping over:

```
$.each(data.slice(0, 20), function( key, val ) {
    items.push( '<li><a href="' + val["key1"] + '">' + val["key2"] + '</a></li>' );
});
```

Comment: Attempting this method does indeed return the first 20 elements, which is awesome, but it does it in the format:

0, [object Object]
1, [object Object]
2, [object Object] 

so on so forth

Comment: I see. That brings a question to mind. You say you want the first 20 entries. In the sample JSON you provided in your question, are there 2 entries showing, or 6 entries showing? You see, there are 2 array entries showing, but 6 object properties showing. What exactly are you looking for.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. In the example that represents two entries.

Comment: Okay, then next question, how do you want the 3 keys displayed in one list item?

Comment: I eventually want it them to be displayed out in one <li> per item, which will have multiple attributes (for example, one key is an img src, another will be an a href, etc.), but I'm not worried about that right now, I just want to make sure I can actually get my data to display from my JSON file into my HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

in the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method JSON data shall be mentioned instead of `[0,19]`

```
$.getJSON( "js/test.json", function( data ) {
      var items = [];
      var i=0;
      $.each(data, function( key, val ) {//<==== data shall be specified instead
        items.push( "<li>" + key + ", " + val + "</li>" );
        if(++i==20) break;//<==== this will break the loop as soon as the counter hits 20
      });
          $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
```

Comment: "//<==== data shall be specified instead" sorry, could you explain what you mean by this? Isn't my data specified by setting "js/test.json" in my url field?

Comment: nope, $.getJSON  load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request. while $.each is another jquery method that helps you Iterate over an array, object, executing a function for each matched element.